# Работа с postgreSQL с django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, postgresql

Не понимаю как решить проблему
Описание модели

```
from django.db import models


class Human(models.Model):
    secondname = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    slug = models.SlugField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.secondname + self.firstname
```

Вывод ошибки

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/..", line 5, in <module>
from .models import Human
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.models'; '__main__' is not a 
package
```

Ответ в этой [теме](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41816973/modulenotfounderror-what-does-it-mean-main-is-not-a-package) не помог

Comment: покажите структуру приложение

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте при импорте явно указать приложение, из которого импортируете модели, например

```
from myapp.models import OneNews
```

Comment: Пробовал, выдает много ошибок связанные с бд.

Comment: Какие например?